# How to return false if a java collection contains two identical elements

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Collection<Event>`. `Event` looks something like this

```
public class Event {

   private Integer id;
   private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

   // getters, setters omitted
```

}

Each `Event` in that `Collection` needs to have a unique `id` and `localDateTime`. How can I do that check using stream API and return true if the condition is satisfied?

Comment: How are `equals()` and `hashCode()` implemented? Do they rely solely on those two properties?

Comment: ^^ *have a unique `id` and `localDateTime`*... unique values of each of them or both in combination?

Comment: Finding whether an iterable has 2 equal elements has the same complexity of sorting it O(n log n). So either you keep an helper `HashSet` to check for membership while you iterate over it to achieve O(n) amortized complexity or you just sort it and iterate over it by "zipping" each element to the next and check for equality.

Comment: @Naman unique values of each of them.

Comment: @downvoter Can you please elaborate why my question is not useful?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use two `HashSet` as backing collections to store unique elements and iterate over the list of events as:

```
public boolean duplicateExists(List<Event> eventList) {
    Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet<>();
    Set<LocalDateTime> localDateTimes = new HashSet<>();
    return eventList.stream()
            .anyMatch(event -> !ids.add(event.getId()) ||
                    !localDateTimes.add(event.getLocalDateTime()));
}
```

Comment: Since `Integer` and `LocalDateTime` can never conflict, you don’t need two `HashSet`s here, a single `HashSet<Object>` would do. But I’d use a loop instead of a `Stream` here.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `Event` class you would need;

```
class Event {

    private Integer id;

    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime() {
        return localDateTime;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        this.localDateTime = localDateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Event event = (Event) o;
        return id.equals(event.id) &&
                localDateTime.equals(event.localDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, localDateTime);
    }

    public static boolean hasDuplicates(List<Event> events) {
        /*
            return events
            .stream()
            .noneMatch(e -> events
                    .stream()
                    .filter(ev -> ev.equals(e)).count() > 1);
         */
         return events.stream()
             .distinct()
             .count() != events.size(); // Kudos to @Holger for this approach.
    }
}
```

This `hasDuplicates` is a `static` function, so it won't make any affect for your object creation. You can use it as a utility method to check duplicates though. You would only need single line of check.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time for the snippet. I was kind of unfamiliar with this method. Now, I think I have some understanding of how it works.

Comment: I guess, you have this confusion because of the `.equals` and `.hashCode` implementation. Refer this to have some undestanding -> https://www.journaldev.com/21095/java-equals-hashcode. Most of the Java core implementations are based on these two methods. If you have override these two methods (override both functions are mandatory hence the equals - hashcode contract), you can simply invoke `event1.equals(event2)` on your objects. That's why `containes()` function also works here.

Comment: This code is nonsense. You're streaming over a items in a list to check that none of those items are contained in that list, which is a contradiction. The only time `hasDuplicates` will return true is when it's given an empty list.

Comment: Streaming over a `List`, to stream again over the list for each element, will end up with a horrible performance (also known as quadratic time complexity). Why don’t you use `return events .stream() .distinct() .count() != events.size();`?

Comment: @Holger, wow that's a great approach. That one never occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, override the method `equals()` and `hashcode()` and write it like so:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
if (o instanceof Event){
    Event e = (Event) o;
    return e.id.equals(this.id) && e.localDateTime.equals(this.localDateTime);
}
else return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
return Objects.hash(id,localDateTime); //this is the default implementation, up to you to implement it in a better way
}
```

Then, you can use the stream like this to check if there are any duplicates:

```
public boolean checkAllUnique(Collection<Event> col){
    return col.stream().allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
}
```

Comment: You're right, I forgot about the cast, correcting it right now

Answer (score -1):

```
 import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
    public class Event {

       private static final AtomicInteger idGenerator = new AtomicInteger(1000);
       private Integer id;
       private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

       public Event(){
          id = idGenerator.getAndIncrement();
       }
       // getters, setters omitted
}
```

Code Test

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i){
            System.out.println(new Event().getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007 1008 1009
```